# Nextjs page.tsx hook issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I wish to render a splash screen in nextjs and after 2secs I wish to navigate to certain screen but I was unable to capitalize on useEffect inside the page.tsx file in nextjs , while importing it is thowing an issue

`You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.`

How can I approach and overcome this issue.Thanks in advance for your help.[image: This is my code image]

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion provided to you in the error message to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `"use client"` on the top of the file

Comment: Its working but why should we use that

Comment: because useEffect can't run on the server you can read more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies on your error in your console, add `"use client"` on top of the page as instructed